# dll Matlab instance throw an exception while running release in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, release-mode

My c# program uses Matlab dll and it works find as long as I run it in Debug mode.
but as I trying to run it in Release mode it crashes immediately when creating it's instance.

It trows TypeInitializationException.

Thanks for your help

StackTrace:

```
"at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
 at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
 at Turbo_Neuron.ANNController..ctor() 
    in C:\\Users\\Eli\\Desktop\\....\\MyProject\\Program.cs:line 17
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
        at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
        at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
        at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
        at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"
```

And it sais:

```
The type initializer for 'MatlabANNComp.MatlabANN' threw an exception.
```

StachTrace 2:

```
   at MatlabANNComp.MatlabANN..ctor()
   at Turbo_Neuron.ANNController..ctor() in C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\Work_ANN\ANN\working\Current\Turbo_Neuron_Pro_Filxed_10.09.13_N\Turbo_Neuron\Matlab_Layer\ANNController.cs:line 49
   at Turbo_Neuron.TNController..ctor(pnl_main form) in C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\Work_ANN\ANN\working\Current\Turbo_Neuron_Pro_Filxed_10.09.13_N\Turbo_Neuron\Logic_Layer\TNController.cs:line 49
   at Turbo_Neuron.pnl_main..ctor() in C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\Work_ANN\ANN\working\Current\Turbo_Neuron_Pro_Filxed_10.09.13_N\Turbo_Neuron\View_Layer\Turbo_Form.cs:line 29
   at Turbo_Neuron.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\Work_ANN\ANN\working\Current\Turbo_Neuron_Pro_Filxed_10.09.13_N\Turbo_Neuron\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Exception messages:

```
Exception.Message = 
"The type initializer for 'MatlabANNComp.MatlabANN' threw an exception."

InnerException.Message =
{"Could not load file or assembly 'MWArray, Version=2.10.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db86f' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made 
to load a program with an incorrect format."}

InnerException.InnerException = null
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and message of the exception - anyway, this exception normally indicates your application can't load the matlab dll. Most likely cause it's not in the search path, or maybe because you also switched platforms

Comment: Stacktrace added, hope it halps, thanks! 
I have only switched from debug to release :(

Comment: there should be more than that in the Exception - also look at the InnerExceptions etc. Here's an example of a similar problem, and the kind of exception information we need to figure out what the root cause is: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46423

Comment: Ok, I added stacktrace2 to my question. With hope that is what you meant.

Comment: no sorry.. the stacktrace is clear enough, it's the exception message that contains the interesting bit. Easiest way to get this is set a breakpoint where you catch the exception, then look at it in the watchwindow and post exception.Message, exception.InnerException.Message, exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message etc if available

Comment: I added exception messages at the bottom. tell me what need to be delete, if there is some unnecessary  information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format`

this is the key, and it means you are mixing platforms somwhow. A 32bit process cannot load 64bit dlls and vice-versa. If a process tries to do so anyway, it throws the above exception.
You say you only changed from Debug->Release, so it's likely something that has to do with platform changed as well. Compare settings for all projects in the Configuration Manager. They all should be x86 or x64 (*not* AnyCPU). Which one depends on your matlab dll's platform (set when building it).

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the configuration-manager.
I did it at the Properties-Build tab. Doesn't work :(